# Can't use Stored Procedure parameter in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm having a lot of troubles with one situation on my DB.

I'm trying to code a Stored Procedure that inserts an entry to a log table for audit purposes after a `SELECT` is done in a specific table (the idea is that it should work similar to how a `AFTER SELECT` Trigger would work). The Stored Procedure has one input parameter, the WHERE condition/clause.

The user executes the SP and writes the condition (for example *IDCultura=1*). The SP uses that parameter to make a `SELECT` statement like this: `SELECT * FROM dba.medicoes WHERE *IDCultura=1*`

My problem arrives when I try to make a cursor that loops the results from that query, so it inserts one line in the log table for each result of the `SELECT`.

I can't use the parameter as `WHERE` clause, but if I manually write the same text in the clause, it works.

I've seen some solutions that use a `CONCAT` to join all the parts of the query before execution. But because I'm using the `SELECT` query when declaring the cursor, I can't `SET` a variable before.

Here's the code I'm working with right now:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `select_medicoes`(
    whereCondicao varchar(200))

BEGIN
DECLARE ID_novo int;
DECLARE ID_Variavel int;
DECLARE ID_Cultura int;
DECLARE NumMed int;
DECLARE DataHoraMed date;
DECLARE ValorMed int;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE curs_medicoeslog cursor for 
    (SELECT *
    FROM `dba`.medicoes
    WHERE `whereCondicao`);

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
SELECT `whereCondicao`;

OPEN curs_medicoeslog;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH curs_medicoeslog INTO ID_Variavel, ID_Cultura, NumMed, DataHoraMed, ValorMed;
            INSERT INTO log_medicoes (IDVariavel, IDCultura, NumMedicao, DataHoraMedicao, ValorMedicao, Utilizador, `Data`, Operacao) 
            VALUES (ID_Variavel, ID_Cultura, NumMed, DataHoraMed, ValorMed, current_user(), now(), 'S');
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
CLOSE curs_medicoeslog;
END
```

Comment: Removed sql server tag as this is clearly mysql.

Comment: Sry for the mistake. And thank you for editing!

Comment: You're welcome. I wish I could help you with an answer but I can't even spell mysql correctly. :)

Comment: It's been a while since I've done something like that; but I seem to recall using dynamic sql to assemble the actual query, with an insert into a temp table; and using a cursor to iterate over that temp table.